# Search in JSON with POSTGRESQL 9.5

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I need to create a query which will search for all values of properties of a JSON.

Example of the table :

```
 ID --- ObjectType --- JSON
 1        Client      {"name":"John","age":27}
 2        Contact     {"contact_name":"Henry","contact_city":"New York"}
```

Each of these JSON formats is in the same a Table.

For example in my app, if I write "27" in my search text box, the query will search for all JSON values (not the properties) the term "27".

If I write "contact_name" in the search text-box, I'll have no results.

I managed to create this query in SQLSERVER 2016

Here is the query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT ObjectTeepee.*
FROM ObjectTeepee
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([previewContent]) as tbValues
WHERE tbValues.value like '%" + param + "%'"
```

I need to do the same, or in another way, in POSTGRESQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `json_each_text` function

```
select ObjectTeepee.* from ObjectTeepee
join  lateral json_each_text(JSON) j
on true
where
j.value = '27'
```

Comment: Just note: Lateral join does not need statement `on true` as well `join` is also optional. You could write the same thing e.g. `... FROM objectteepee t, json_each_text(previewcontent) j WHERE j.value = '27'`.

Comment: @KristoMägi - Yes, I just prefer that style.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM ObjectTeepee
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM jsonb_each(previewContent) WHERE value='27'
)
```